# Expression Studio Install Breaks Machine

Tags: windows-xp, directx

I've now tried installing Expression Studio 3 three times (downloaded via the WebSiteSpark) program.  The first two I tried a mounted ISO, and for the third, I wrote the image to CD.  With all three, a few seconds after booting, and a BSOD that requires speed-reading to comprehend, the machine restarts, ad infinitum.

I can start in safe mode and do a system restore to a checkpoint created yesterday, before the logged changes for today, which are "Installed DirectX".  After the restore, everything is fine.

I'm running XP SP2 on an HP Pavilion dv9205us, but had to cheat and use drivers for another HP, as no XP drivers are available for this one.  Any advice on how to diagnose or fix this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing DirectX 9 on its own from the MS web installer before trying the Expression install again solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go in to Control Panel > System > Advanced > Startup and Recovery and choose "Disable automatic restart on system failure".

You may also want to try [Blue Screen View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), a utility that will tell you about previous blue screens that you have had.

As far as I know, Expressions Studio does not install any drivers and runs as standard software, if you are having crashes, this could indicate a more serious fault such as faulty memory etc.

Comment: The fault completely disappears when I do a system restore to before Expression, but when I feel like going through all that several times again, I will give Blue Screen View a shot, thanks.

Comment: I understand, however what I am trying to say is that anything that runs as standard "software" should never be able to cause a blue screen, some software that runs other devices to the limits (memory, I/O, graphics etc.... such as rendering within expressions) push other items to the limits and can show the weaknesses in them... so, updating a seemingly unrelated driver, could solve your problem.